# How to fetch the website code in my local machine?

Tags: git

I have a local GIT repository in my system by name 'git_repo' under which I had the whole codebase for a website (pre-configured by someone else), including all the jsps, js, css etc.

I used the following commands to create the local git repository out of the main repository:

```
git branch //to show the current branch
git checkout -b branch_local_name origin/Main_branch_name //to create local repository in current branch
git fetch //to fetch the current build
```

Accidentally, I deleted all the contents of the local folder and I don't know what to do fetch the contents of that website again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you simply use clone?

```
 git clone <remote-repo> <local-dir-that-is-empty>
```

After doing this, you can do branching and stuff.

Running these commands in succession should do it:

```
cd ~
mkdir new_repo
cd new_repo
git clone <path-to-repo> .
```

Comment: can u guide me with reference to this>>

Comment: vverma@l-vverma:~/git_repo/nextag$ git branch
      BR_PS_1109
    * br_ps
      master
    vverma@l-vverma:~/git_repo/nextag$ git clone BR_PS_1109
    fatal: repository 'BR_PS_1109' does not exist
    vverma@l-vverma:~/git_repo/nextag$ git clone br_ps
    fatal: repository 'br_ps' does not exist
    vverma@l-vverma:~/git_repo/nextag$ git clone master
    fatal: repository 'master' does not exist

Comment: I've added more instructions to my answer. You will need to provide the full path to the respository.

Comment: path is ind-git.corp.nextag.com

Comment: You will need to prepend the protocol to use for the connection. You can try `git clone git://ind-git.corp.nextag.com .` or `git clone ssh://ind-git.corp.nextag.com .` As far as I can tell, however, the domain ind-git.corp.nextag.com doesn't even exist.

Comment: it says: Cloning into 'ind-git.corp.nextag.com'...
fatal: unable to connect to :
: Name or service not known

Comment: when i execute <<git remote>> it returns the result <<origin>>

Comment: Did your remember the "." at the end, with a space in front of it? That's important.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git branch -a | grep BR_SO // to show all the branches
$ git checkout -b bug-<Jira_ID> origin/BR_<name> // make fix in the BR
$ git fetch
```

and this will solve it